# Adding Users to AD using New-ADUser and Splatting

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've run into issue using splatting with the New-ADUser cmdlet. I've been able to add all the normal attributes using splatting, but now I need to add an extension attributes as part of the parameters for the new user.

I'm creating an array as follows:

```
$users = @{ “name” = “fred 
“givenName” = “Manfred" 
“l” = “lexington”
"extensionAttrbute1" = "Test"}
```

But when I run the script, it gives me the following errors: "InvalidArgument", 
"ParameterBindingException" and "NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser"

And the actual exception message is this:
"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'extensionAttribute1'" 
I can actually add the extensionAttribute directly using New-ADUSer, but adding in as part of the array is the likely issue. Do I need to preface the extensionAttribute differently in the array or something?

Thanks,
Bjarne

Comment: You're creating a hashtable. Each key value pair has to be followed by a semicolon like ```$a=@{ key1="value1"; key2="value2" }```

Comment: Great comment. I'm actually using the .Add command on the hashtable to create the individual objects.

Answer (score 1):

Get the user with `Get-ADUser` and use the `-Properties` Parameter to specify your extensionAttribute.

Afterwards use `Set-ADUser` to set the extensionAttribute:

E.g.

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $yourIdentity -Properties extensionAttribute1
Set-ADUser –Identity $user -Clear "extensionAttribute1"
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Add @{ extensionAttribute1 = "your value" }
```

Comment: That's a sound approach. However, I'm not guaranteed that I'm talking to the DC on which the user object is created and thus I may not be able to update the user.

Answer (score 1):

From the TechNet on [New-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx). Property values that are not associated with cmdlet parameters can be set by using the `OtherAttributes` parameter. When using this parameter be sure to place single quotes around the attribute name as in the following example.

```
$users = @{ 
    "name" = “fred 
    "givenName" = “Manfred" 
    "l" = "lexington"
    "OtherAttributes" = @{ 
        'extensionAttrbute1' = "Test"
     }
}
```